# Conversion calculation from string do double

Tags: java, android

i'm working in android and I need your help. In **string** in **values** I have this

```
<item>(1 / 1024)</item>
```

I need to parse this string to double this way

```
outputDouble = Double.parseDouble(unitsValues[outputPosition]);
```

so it means this

```
outputDouble = Double.parseDouble((1 / 1024));
```

This second code mean, that I find the line by index I need and it tries to convert it from string to double but it is impossible because it can recognize this string (1 / 1024) to double. Do you have any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Very similar to the following questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/java-evaluate-string-to-math-expression

Comment: android doesnt support ScriptEngineManager package, so there is a problem

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in method to do that ... However you could do that with an external library like [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/) :

```
Interpreter interpreter = new Interpreter();
interpreter.eval("(1 / 1024)");
```

To use Beanshell with Android, download the bsh-core.jar file, put it in a /lib folder in your project, and adjust your Eclipse settings or Ant script to reference that JAR during compilation and packaging.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will illustrate you how to do the parsing using the `String#split`. There is no direct method to do the conversion.

```
String representation = getString(R.string.my_repr);
String [] splits  = representation.split("/");
Double num = Double.valueOf(splits[0].trim()) / Double.valueOf(splits[1].trim());
```

**EDIT** I also added trimming to the strings, because of the danger of spurious interval symbols.

Comment: and If I have more complicated code like <item>(1/(1024 * 1024))</item> and so on?

Comment: Read about the Interpreter design pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_pattern). Better if you find the Gang of Four book (http://www.amazon.com/Design-Patterns-Elements-Reusable-Object-Oriented/dp/0201633612), not the wikipedia stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Using `regex` parse `(1 / 1024)` into two `Double` values `1f` and `1024f` and then divide them to get a `Double` value.

Comment: ok, very easy idea, but it takes a time until a resolve the examples like <item>(1/(1024 * 1024))</item>, <item>(1/(1024 * 1024 * 1024))</item> and so on